# Get the hit row in MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Let us say we have the next JSON structure:

```
{
   {
      name:"FirstComponent",
      items:[
         {
            Caption:"Item1",
            Value:"1"
         },
         {
            Caption:"Item2",
            Value:"3"
         },
         {
            Caption:"Item3",
            Value:"2"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Let us say we query for the item with value "2". `{"items.Value":"2"}` and we would get the whole document back. What I want to have is an index of subdocument it hit on, it would be nice from my scenario.

Is there a way to get some indication on which is the first document which hit the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that wouldn't make sense: where would it store the index in the document it returns to you?

You need to just scan the array again in C# to find the index if you really need it.

Comment: that was my idea but it is scaning once again anyhow. It could return the index on a specialized command like "show index" which could be implemented as an analog of "explain".

Comment: But the second 'scanning' is in C# code on a small in-memory datastructure so it's in the microseconds.

Comment: Yes, its time consumption is minimal but I feel like this would make the code more ugly and the other developer's on the team will not be aware. It is more like a patch

Comment: I need to display only the first subdocument which hit alongside the root level info and if they had such feature it would suit my case perfectly. Thanks for you response